# What's the difference with my two sql to find repeated record in Oralce?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to delete and leave only one record if the record is repeated.In my table t_id is a primary key which is int type and automatic increate,and id is a serial number and is varchar type.
At first,my sql is like this.but it seems deadlock,and runs very long time and seems never stop.

```
delete from tbtest
Where t_id Not In (
select max(t_id) from tbtest having count(id)>1  
group by id
 )
and  id in (
select id   from tbtest group by id having count(id)>1 
) 
and create_time<to_timestamp('2016-02-25 11:26:52','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

So I change it to the other way,and it runs very quickly?What's the difference between them?

```
delete from tbtest where t_id in (
 select  t_id   from tbtest 
Where t_id Not In (
select max(t_id) from tbtest having count(id)>1  
group by id
)
and  id in (
select id   from tbtest group by id having count(id)>1 
) 
and create_time<=to_timestamp('2016-02-25 11:26:52','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') 
)
```

Comment: You do not have a deadlock.  That requires two sessions.  Run explain plan on your statements and post the results.

Comment: So, do you have only two columns in the table? If you have more than two columns, do you know for sure that if the serial number `id` is the same, then everything else is the same? Or perhaps you don't care - if you have the same id, you only want, for every serial number `id`, to keep only the row with the highest `t_id` (presumably the most recent one)?

Comment: Yes,I want one record if the id is the same

Comment: There have more than two columns.But I do not care other column.I want to make sure that the id is unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proof of concept. Try it out and see if it helps.

```
create table ta ( t_id number primary key, id varchar2(10), val number );

insert into ta 
    select 1, '1', 33 from dual union all
    select 2, '2', 44 from dual union all
    select 3, '2', 55 from dual;

commit;

select * from ta;

      T_ID ID                VAL
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 1                  33
         2 2                  44
         3 2                  55

delete from ta
where t_id in (select t_id from (select t_id, id, 
      row_number() over (partition by id order by t_id desc) rn from ta) where rn > 1);

1 row deleted.

select * from ta;

      T_ID ID                VAL
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 1                  33
         3 2                  55
```

Comment: I apologize, I re-read the question and it didn't ask for a solution, it asked what the difference was between the two queries. I find the queries hard to follow, so I didn't try very hard to answer THAT question. Even so, I hope this solution may help.

Comment: I use your example and both two way can run well.May be the test data is little.But in my own database the first way is so slow.

Comment: I think I was able to follow your first query (the one that takes a long time). I don't understand why you need to filter by id (to look only at those that have more than one row). If the t_id is not equal to the maximum t_id for that id, then that id automatically must have at least two rows. Remove that additional check (for id in ....) and see if that improves performance.

Comment: Also, what I was suggesting to try was the solution, not the sample data :-)  This solution may (or may not) run faster than both your queries.